# Should MVC method be get or post and how to call in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have this method on one of my controllers for getting a dropdownlist:

```
public JsonResult GetPeople(int roleId)
{
    return Json(_uow.GetPeople(roleId).Select(e => new SelectListItem { Text = e.Name, Value = e.Id.ToString() }).ToList());
}
```

so basically it gets a whole bunch of people within a particular role and returns a selectlistitem list in json.

I'm unsure whether it should be decorated with [HttpGet] or [HttpPost]. I'm thinking it should be a get because that's essentially what your doing, getting info from the server even though you do post an id.

So it has no decoration so by default is a GET.

This is how I call it in jquery:

```
$.get('/People/GetPeople', { roleId: $('#roleddl').val() }, function (data) {

    $(data).each(function () {
        $("<option value=" + this.Value + ">" + this.Text + "</option>").appendTo(peopleddl);
    });

});
```

So here I'm using the $.get. It didn't work. So I was thinking it's returning json so I tried $.getJSON which didn't work. So then I tried $.post and it worked as:

```
$.post('/People/GetPeople', { roleId: $('#roleddl').val() }, function (data) {

    $(data).each(function () {
        $("<option value=" + this.Value + ">" + this.Text + "</option>").appendTo(peopleddl);
    });

});
```

So I'm wondering why is a jquery post call working when the method it is calling is no a POST.

Also even though this works what combination should I have. ie. What should the method be decorated with and what should I use to call it?

Comment: Sounds to me like you got confused and didn't specify it as a GET but put it as a POST.  Are you sure?  Also, it is standard in this case to use GET because you are retrieving a particular resource (as you said).

Comment: When you don't mark an action with [HttpGet] or [HttpPost] it can be accessible by both methods. In your case the GET fails due to security reasons.

Comment: @Mark - To with not specifying JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet?

Comment: You should specify JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet for GET requests

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your return statement to allow returning Json:

```
return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Json has a known vulnerability when returned over a GET response (more here: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx)